# Pixi Js, CanvasRenderer error

Tags: pixi.js

I use pixi.js v 3.0.0 
My simple code is

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        var width = screen.availWidth;
        var height = screen.availHeight;
        var renderer = PIXI.CanvasRenderer(width, height, {
                backgroundColor : 0x1099bb
            });

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
        var stage = new PIXI.Container();

        var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('asset/bunny.png');

        var bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

        bunny.anchor.x = 0.5;
        bunny.anchor.y = 0.5;

        bunny.position.x = 200;
        bunny.position.y = 150;

        stage.addChild(bunny);
        animate();
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            bunny.rotation += 0.1;
            renderer.render(stage);
        }
    }, false);
}
());
```

But i get: `TypeError: this.initPlugins is not a function` if use CanvasRenderer but it works in other cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `new` keyword when creating the CanvasRenderer.